# How to limit dynamic queries to only accept select statements?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, oracle10g

Currently I allow admin users to query the database by providing a dynamic query with this method:

```
public DataSet executeRawQuery(final String q) {
    JdbcDataSet dataSet = jdbcTpl.execute(q, new DataSetBuildingCallback(settingsProvider));
    return dataSet;
}
```

However, I want to allow them to use only `select` statements and block table drop, delete, etc. statements. How can I do it?

The SQL statements can be quite complex so I wouldn't like having to check the string for keywords. Is there a **Spring's** built-in functionality that could help me with this?

Comment: This is a case where I think writing more code would be a better idea.  Explicitly break out the select and update query execution.  That's how JDBC does it.  Parsing SQL destroys the benefit of the abstraction.

Comment: This is quite a security hole, but if you really must, I'd suggest using database credentials that only allow select. That way, the security is at the database layer and any attempt to delete, insert, update or drop will result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, there's no need for checking the input string, just let the database itself handle the security and use a database connection that will **only** allow `select` statements.

To do that, first create a database user and only grant `select`:

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY apassword;
GRANT CONNECT TO username;
GRANT SELECT on schema.table TO username;
```

and then use the username/password created above when getting the JDBC connection. If other parts of the application need insert/delete/update then they can use another connection.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look if this option is feasible and will respond here.